# sparks cluster is unable to find txt files present in zip folder passed to it

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a zip folder `ce.zip` containing python & text files, that I pass to the sparks cluster in the following way.

```
\bin\spark-submit.cmd --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.0 --py-files ce.zip main.py
```

But it is showing error on a particular line of the python file that's is trying to access the text file as follows,

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...\\ce.zip\\detectors\\files\\device_features.txt'
```

But it works when I hard code the required file path & keep it outside the zip file.

Am I missing something or passing it in the wrong way?

Comment: try with absolute/full path

Comment: @shaileshgupta yeah, it works well with hardcoded full path.